# SQL Table Columns Missing When Imported Into Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I have a table that lives in SQL Server, I imported the table into Access through External Data > New Data Source > From Database. I went through the whole authentication process. After choosing the correct Database and table that I wanted imported, most columns in the table were imported, but some were not. Why would some columns be missing?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18.12.1.

- I tried checking to see if these missing columns were computed columns, but that shows False in SQL Server.

Comment: What data types are the missing columns? Perhaps there’s no path to import due to failed type conversions

Comment: It looks like all the columns missing are of data type float.

Comment: You may get a useful response if you publish the table definition and sample data as text.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with access part of your process. Might wanna check when you chosen table what that wizard said, perhaps it displays list of columns

Comment: @siggemannen When I go through the process it actually doesn't let me choose which columns specifically I want imported, it just defaults to all, but excludes some.

Comment: Strange, i tested locally, and floats were imported fine. I think you'll have to include the table definition :)

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out MS Access only imports up to 255 columns from a table (the table didn't import past column number 255).  If anyone can help me be able to select specific columns I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access has a [limit](https://www.easysoft.com/blog/access-column-limit.html) of 255 columns per table. If you attempt to link to an external table that has more than 255 columns, Access will retrieve the first 255 columns only.

My work around was creating a new table in SQL Server with the columns that I needed and importing that table instead.